# Read cookies with JSTL

Tags: jsp, cookies, jstl

I was studying about cookies and was able to create and read them using scriptlet-based JSP,however when I tried to do the same using JSTL it's not displaying all my cookies, only "JSESSIONID ..." and with my other project it shows the cookie that I created. My question here is why, it seems right for me but not for my browser..
Here is what I'm trying to do using JSTL:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>

<c:forEach var="cookieVal" items="${requestScope.cookies}" > 
    <tr>
        <td align="right">${cookieVal.name}</td>
        <td>${cookieVal.value}</td>
    </tr>
</c:forEach>
```

And my other project working:

```
<% Cookie[] cookies = request.getCookies();
for (int i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
    Cookie cookie = cookies[i];%>
    <tr>
        <td><%=cookie.getName()%></td>
        <td><%=cookie.getValue()%></td>
    </tr>
<%}%>
```

And I have m JSTL .jars inside my project libraries folder...
Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`requestScope.cookies` will search for an request attribute named `cookies`. If you want to access the cookies property of the request, you need `pageContext.request.cookies`.

That said, accessing cookies is something you should do with Java code, inside a controller (servlet), and not in the view (JSP), which should only deal with HTML generation.

Comment: I forgot to tell, I actually have this attribute ( `Cookie[] cookies = request.getCookies();` ) and found my problem (so stupid by the way...) I was actually adding my new cookie to my `response` attribute instead of my `request`... So stupid this haha but thank you!

Answer (score 6):

You can access cookie value named `cookeName` by `${cookie.cookieName.value}`