# How to retrieve cookie values from java to jsp

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

```
String userNmae = req.getParameter("userName");
Cookie ck = new Cookie("hello", vall);
res.addCookie(ck);
```

//lets suppose, I've stored 5 different users name or integer in cookie.

```
Cookie [] cookies = req.getCookies();
            String name;
        for(Cookie cookie : cookies) {
                 name = cookie.getValue();
                req.setAttribute("vav", name);
                req.getRequestDispatcher("index.jsp").forward(req, res);
              }
```

//Now I would like to retrieve all the values and display on jsp page. How would I do that..

```
${vav}
```

jsp file..
Thank you all in advance..

Answer (score 1):

To display cookie value into a JSP, use this code:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>

<c:forEach var="cookieVal" items="${pageContext.request.cookies}" > 
    <tr>
        <td align="right">${cookieVal.name}</td>
        <td>${cookieVal.value}</td>
    </tr>
</c:forEach>
```

This piece of code was originally taken from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21939493/read-cookies-with-jstl).

I hope this helps.